# PCI-DSS Certification for Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pci-dss

Recently (2nd Dec 2014) Google [announced](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.in/2014/12/google-cloud-platform-now-pci-data-security-standard-certified.html) that Google Cloud Platform is now PCI-DSS compliant.

Since then there have been no updates on the same. I have checked the public forums, stackoverflow, google developers site to no avail.

I am looking to develop my app on the cloud platform, but require all the necessary steps that should be followed in order to be compliant. Does anyone has any ideas regarding the same?

Answer (score 1):

Google have certified their platform is compliant.

If you are building an application, you will need to follow the guidelines to ensure that the software you are writing is compliant.

Also, you will need to follow the guidelines when configuring Google's platform (for example, if you open up all firewall ports and set the root password on a bunch of GCE instances to "password" then your application will NOT be compliant).

I expect that if you have a premier account you could request a copy of the PCI-DSS certificate from Google - but it's only *part* of the picture.